# How to output xml using c# elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm creating a site, I have a payment gateway i want to integrate, all I need is to pass some of my c# elements to the web service, I need to output an xml file with my elements.
Please how do I do this?

The request that needs to be sent is as follows:

```
<PaymentRequest>
<ProductName>Match Ticket</ProductName>   (Static value)                                                                                                                                
<Prefix>Mr</Prefix>  (Prefix of the booker)                                                                                                                                                                                                    
<FirstName>Test</FirstName>  (First name of the user)                                                                                                                                                               
<LastName>Test</LastName>   (Last name of the user)                                                                                                                                                               
<Address>Test Address</Address>  Address of the user(can be a dummy value in case the customer did not fill this)                                                                                                                                                        
<City>London</City> City of user(can be a dummy value in case the customer did not fill this)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
<Country>UK</Country> Country of user(can be a dummy value in case the customer did not fill this) 
<Mobile>98231283123</Mobile> (user phone no)                                                                                                                                                            
<EmailId>test@test.com</EmailId> (user email)                                                                                                                       
<PaymentMethod>PayatBank</PaymentMethod> (this will be the option selected)                                                                                              
<TotalAmount>13314</TotalAmount> (total amount, this is already a label)                                                                                                                                   

<Amount>12926</Amount>   (Base amount of the booking)                                                                                                                                                                    
<GatewayCharge>388</GatewayCharge> (Credit card charges)                                                                                                                            
<GatewayChargeInPercent>3</GatewayChargeInPercent>                                                             
<CallBackURL>http://www.google.com</CallBackURL>                                                                    Link where the user will get redirected after the payment has been made. This will be used for online payments only. 
</PaymentRequest>
```

Comment: You could make a `PaymentRequest` class and serialize it with [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, need to research xmlserializer

Answer (score 0):

You should use XmlSerializer. You can use this helper if you want :

```
public static class XmlSerializationHelper
{
    public static string Serialize<T>(T value)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);

        return writer.ToString();
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string rawValue)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(rawValue);

        T value = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Maybe make some research next time. I dont think this is too hard to find.

I took it from this [blog](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/02/20/last-xml-serializer-i-ll-ever-write/). Thanks to him.

Comment: Hi aloisgd, thanks for the answer, but how do I call this in my radio button action? and also how do i use this to add my elements in the XML?

Comment: You need to create a custom class which will represent a `PaymentRequest`, and in the above code, wherever you see `T` you will replace with your custom class.

Comment: @Kenneth What are you using ? WPF I guess ? You seem to start. Maybe just learn some basics before using this helper.